# syntax issues with js/jquery assignment - Quiz questions in an object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to work through an assignment to further my understanding of js but I'm running into some issues that are keeping me from final code. The code executes a short quiz- inputs from radio buttons are taken in and matched to an object containing answers, then outputting a final score.

code at http://jsfiddle.net/8ax9A/3/

issues I'm aware of now :
my $response variable doesn't seem to work.

```
var $response = $('[name=rad]:checked').val();
```

counter is listening for clicks through questions. After the last question, I want to report final score. I can't get counter to reach the end of questions + 1, and I cant get an accurate final score listener reported (var finalScore).

```
 if ($response == parseInt(questions[counter].answer, 10)) {
            finalScore++;
        }
```

Those are just snippets so check out the fiddle for full code. I'd love some suggestions on how to understand where I'm going wrong.

Comment: Not the solution, but all your radio buttons have the same id "rad". An ID must be unique!

Comment: Also not the solution, but you don't need to `parseInt()` a variable that's already an integer.

Comment: ha thanks guys all helpful :)  i didnt think parseInt was needed but i picked it up from another student's fiddle sample. I've removed that and updated the id's.

Comment: don't look for the value until button is clicked. `$response` won't update itself when user changes radio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way you could do it:

```
//Initialization
var counter=0;
var score=0;

loadQuestion();
$('#next').on('click',answer);


//functions

function answer(){
    // if the user did not answer
    if ($('input:radio:checked').length == 0){
        alert('You have to answer!');
        return;
    }
    var currentQ=questions[counter];
    // if answer is correct
    if($('[name=rad]:checked').val()==currentQ.answer){score++;}
    counter++;
    // if there are no questions left
    if(counter >= questions.length) {displayResults(); return;}
    loadQuestion();
}

function loadQuestion(){
    // clear the radio buttons
    $("input:checked").removeAttr("checked");
    var currentQ=questions[counter];
    // display the question
    $('h1').text(currentQ.question);
    $('#a1').text(currentQ.choices[0]);
    $('#a2').text(currentQ.choices[1]);
    $('#a3').text(currentQ.choices[2]);
}

function displayResults(){
    $("h1").text("You've finished with a score of " + score + "!");
    $('[name=rad], #a1, #a2, #a3, #next').remove();
}
```

#### JS Fiddle

Comment: thanks Blex this is great- just one edit I'd like to make. Instead of alerting the final score I'd like to replace the copy on screen. Something like: 

    function displayResults(){
    $("h1").text("You've finished with a score of " + finalScore + "!");
    $("#a1").remove();
    $("#a2").remove();
    $("#a3").remove();
    $('[name=rad]').remove();}
    }); 

but that doesnt appear to work..?

Comment: There you go darnen! Note that you can merge these `.remove()` all together. I also updated the JSFiddle.

Comment: excellent! thanks so much. Right now I appear to be better at reading js than writing. I guess practice makes perfect. At least your solution makes sense to me. Thanks again :)

Comment: It looks like you had extra brackets and parenthesis in your comment. Yes, breaking it down into clearly named functions makes it easier to read and to debug.